# Dry Hydrogen Production

Tags: experimental-chemistry, purification

I am building a set-up to produce a controlled flow of dry hydrogen. I'm aiming for around 99.5 percent purity.

Am I right in thinking a PEM cell and Deterite drying tube should be fine for this? Or will I need a condenser of some kind?

Any tips?

Comment: Some links that might be useful for people reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_exchange_membrane_fuel_cell and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drying_tube

Comment: What you should be really careful about is storing it$\ldots$Hydrogen gas is highly explosive (even though its potential energy is well-hidden behind a kinetic barrier) but I guess you already know that.

Comment: If you might ultimately need ultra-pure hydrogen, palladium membrane hydrogen purifiers are a simple way to eliminate trace gases.

Comment: For what setting up a fuel cell would costs you can buy high purity hydrogen in a tank. It is a cheap gas to make in production quantities. The expensive part will be the regulator.

Answer (score 1):

Using molecular sieves comes to my mind, they're easy to use and efficient. You can find some practical information about how this is done for example here http://www.klmtechgroup.com/PDF/Articles/articles/Molecular-Sieve-Applications.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen gas is inert towards most common drying agents, so you could try using a drying tube filled with anhydrous salts like CaCl2, Na2SO4, MgSO4 or you can bubble it through cc.H2SO4. But molecular sieves are also a good bet if you have them.